# Set zoom for polygon in osmdroid

Tags: android, zooming, polygon, osmdroid

I want to show an polygon with osmdroid. The polygon appears but how can is set the correct zoomlevel and zoom-position for this polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BoundingBoxE6 bb = BoundingBoxE6.fromGeoPoints(polygon.getPoints());
mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(bb, true);
```

With an important constraint: you cannot do that in onCreate (See [osmdroid issue 324](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/324))